# How To Connect Qt Android application to the MySQL Server?

Tags: android, mysql, qt

I want to connect my android application which i made by Qt to the MySQL server.
Desktop application is able to connect MySQL but android not?
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build Qt MySQL plugin for Android. Here is the detailed instruction how to do that: http://wiki.qt.io/Build_Qt5_mysql_plugin_for_Android

The idea is that you need first to compile all the prerequisites like OpenSSL and libiconv and then compile mariadbclient which is preferred way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I'll implement then let you know. :-) 2

Comment: Has anyone managed to build the plugin using these instructions? I have tried several time but failed on Windows. Do we have pre-built drivers/plugins for android. There are almost no new materials developed to this cause with Qt.